# Proving local non-satiation in arbitrary metric space

Tags: economics

I have a pure exchange economy where every consumption set $X_i$ is non-empty and convex and every preference relation $\succeq_{i}$ is strictly convex. I am asked to show that preferences are locally non-satiated at any consumption bundle different from the single ‘satiation point’ (i.e. the bundle which is strictly preferred to all other bundles in the consumption set; I have already proved that the satiation point, $x^*$, is unique).

So far I have:

Consider an arbitrary $x_{i}\in X_{i}$. Consider $\hat{x}:=\phi x_i+(1-\phi)x^*$, $\phi\in(0,1)$. Consider an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Now, choose $\phi$ such that the distance between $\hat{x}$ and $x_{i}$ is less than $\epsilon$. That is, $\phi\in(0,1)$ such that $\phi x_i+(1-\phi)x^*<\epsilon$. I get that $\phi<\frac{\epsilon+x_{i}-x^{*}}{x_{i}-x^{*}}$.  We must have that $\phi\in(0, \min\{1, \frac{\epsilon+x_{i}-x^{*}}{x_{i}-x^{*}}\})$. Also, note that, by strict convexity, $\hat{x}\succ x_{i}$.

Beyond this point I am stuck. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.